# Error during visual studio 2010 installation

Tags: visual-studio, installation

I have installed Service Pack 3 and installer 4.5 but still I am getting error during visual studio installation. I have tried few manuals over internet but nothing worked...
Here is my error log:

> **[08/17/12,00:10:17] VS Scenario: [2]**  Blocking Components exist and must be satisified before continuing to install 
>   **[08/17/12,00:10:17] VS Scenario: [2] Windows XP Service Pack 3 is
>   required [08/17/12,00:10:17] VS Scenario: [2] Windows Installer 3.1 or
>   higher is required. [08/17/12,00:10:17] VS Scenario: [2]**  End of
>   Blocking Component List ** [08/17/12,00:10:35] VS Scenario: [2]
>   Failed to pass the Warnings/Blocks checks in CVSScenario::Start()
>   [08/18/12,02:29:47] Microsoft Application Error Reporting: [2]
>   CMsiComponent::Install() expects the setup file for Microsoft
>   Application Error Reporting, but the file failed verification.
>   [08/18/12,02:29:48] setup.exe: [2] ISetupComponent::Pre/Post/Install()
>   failed in ISetupManager::InternalInstallManager() with HRESULT
>   -2147467259. [08/18/12,02:29:48] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Application Error Reporting is not installed.
>   [08/18/12,02:29:48] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates VC 9.0 Runtime
>   (x86) was not attempted to be installed. [08/18/12,02:29:48] VS70pgui:
>   [2] DepCheck indicates VC 10.0 Runtime (x86) was not attempted to be
>   installed. [08/18/12,02:29:48] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates
>   Microsoft .NET Framework 4 was not attempted to be installed.
>   [08/18/12,02:29:48] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Windows
>   Installer 4.5 (x86) - Windows XP was not attempted to be installed.
>   [08/18/12,02:29:48] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Windows
>   Installer 4.5 Update (x86) - Windows XP was not attempted to be
>   installed. [08/18/12,02:29:48] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates
>   Microsoft Visual F# 2.0 Runtime was not attempted to be installed.
>   [08/18/12,02:29:48] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual
>   Studio Macro Tools was not attempted to be installed.
>   [08/18/12,02:29:48] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates TFS Object Model
>   (x86) was not attempted to be installed. [08/18/12,02:29:48] VS70pgui:
>   [2] DepCheck indicates .NET Framework 4 Multi-Targeting Pack was not
>   attempted to be installed. [08/18/12,02:29:48] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck
>   indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU was not
>   attempted to be installed. [08/18/12,02:29:48] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck
>   indicates Microsoft Web Deployment Tool (x86) was not attempted to be
>   installed. [08/18/12,02:29:48] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates
>   Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 2 - Visual Studio 2010 Tools was not attempted
>   to be installed. [08/18/12,02:29:48] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates
>   Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 2 was not attempted to be installed.
>   [08/18/12,02:29:48] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft
>   Silverlight was not attempted to be installed. [08/18/12,02:29:48]
>   VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Silverlight 3 SDK was not
>   attempted to be installed. [08/18/12,02:29:48] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck
>   indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime (x86)
>   was not attempted to be installed. [08/18/12,02:29:48] VS70pgui: [2]
>   DepCheck indicates Microsoft Office Developer Tools (x86) was not
>   attempted to be installed. [08/18/12,02:29:48] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck
>   indicates Dotfuscator Software Services - Community Edition was not
>   attempted to be installed. [08/18/12,02:29:48] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck
>   indicates Crystal Reports templates for Visual Studio 2010 was not
>   attempted to be installed. [08/18/12,02:29:48] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck
>   indicates Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 (x86) ENU was not
>   attempted to be installed. [08/18/12,02:29:48] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck
>   indicates Visual Studio 2010 Tools for SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 ENU
>   was not attempted to be installed. [08/18/12,02:29:48] VS70pgui: [2]
>   DepCheck indicates Microsoft Sync Framework Runtime v1.0 (x86) ENU was
>   not attempted to be installed. [08/18/12,02:29:48] VS70pgui: [2]
>   DepCheck indicates Microsoft Sync Services for ADO.NET v2.0 (x86) ENU
>   was not attempted to be installed. [08/18/12,02:29:48] VS70pgui: [2]
>   DepCheck indicates Microsoft Sync Framework Services v1.0 (x86) ENU
>   was not attempted to be installed. [08/18/12,02:29:48] VS70pgui: [2]
>   DepCheck indicates Microsoft Sync Framework SDK v1.0 (x86) ENU was not
>   attempted to be installed. [08/18/12,02:29:48] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck
>   indicates Microsoft SQL Publishing Wizard 1.4 was not attempted to be
>   installed. [08/18/12,02:29:48] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates
>   Microsoft SQL Server System CLR Types was not attempted to be
>   installed. [08/18/12,02:29:48] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates
>   Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Objects was not attempted to
>   be installed. [08/18/12,02:29:48] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates
>   Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Express Service Pack 1 (x86) was not
>   attempted to be installed. [08/18/12,02:29:48] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck
>   indicates Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Data-Tier Application Framework
>   was not attempted to be installed. [08/18/12,02:29:48] VS70pgui: [2]
>   DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Data-Tier Application
>   Project was not attempted to be installed. [08/18/12,02:29:48]
>   VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2
>   Transact-SQL Language Service was not attempted to be installed.
>   [08/18/12,02:29:48] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft
>   SharePoint Developer Tools was not attempted to be installed.
>   [08/18/12,02:29:48] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual
>   Studio 2010 ADO.NET Entity Framework Tools was not attempted to be
>   installed. [08/18/12,02:29:48] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates
>   Microsoft Help Viewer 1.0 x86 was not attempted to be installed.
>   [08/18/12,02:42:52] Microsoft Application Error Reporting: [2]
>   CMsiComponent::Install() expects the setup file for Microsoft
>   Application Error Reporting, but the file failed verification.
>   [08/18/12,02:42:52] setup.exe: [2] ISetupComponent::Pre/Post/Install()
>   failed in ISetupManager::InternalInstallManager() with HRESULT
>   -2147467259. [08/18/12,02:42:52] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Application Error Reporting is not installed.
>   [08/18/12,02:42:52] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates VC 9.0 Runtime
>   (x86) was not attempted to be installed. [08/18/12,02:42:52] VS70pgui:
>   [2] DepCheck indicates VC 10.0 Runtime (x86) was not attempted to be
>   installed. [08/18/12,02:42:52] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates
>   Microsoft .NET Framework 4 was not attempted to be installed.
>   [08/18/12,02:42:52] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Windows
>   Installer 4.5 Update (x86) - Windows XP was not attempted to be
>   installed. [08/18/12,02:42:52] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates
>   Microsoft Visual F# 2.0 Runtime was not attempted to be installed.
>   [08/18/12,02:42:52] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual
>   Studio Macro Tools was not attempted to be installed.
>   [08/18/12,02:42:52] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates TFS Object Model
>   (x86) was not attempted to be installed. [08/18/12,02:42:52] VS70pgui:
>   [2] DepCheck indicates .NET Framework 4 Multi-Targeting Pack was not
>   attempted to be installed. [08/18/12,02:42:52] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck
>   indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU was not
>   attempted to be installed. [08/18/12,02:42:52] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck
>   indicates Microsoft Web Deployment Tool (x86) was not attempted to be
>   installed. [08/18/12,02:42:52] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates
>   Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 2 - Visual Studio 2010 Tools was not attempted
>   to be installed. [08/18/12,02:42:52] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates
>   Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 2 was not attempted to be installed.
>   [08/18/12,02:42:52] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft
>   Silverlight was not attempted to be installed. [08/18/12,02:42:52]
>   VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Silverlight 3 SDK was not
>   attempted to be installed. [08/18/12,02:42:52] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck
>   indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime (x86)
>   was not attempted to be installed. [08/18/12,02:42:52] VS70pgui: [2]
>   DepCheck indicates Microsoft Office Developer Tools (x86) was not
>   attempted to be installed. [08/18/12,02:42:52] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck
>   indicates Dotfuscator Software Services - Community Edition was not
>   attempted to be installed. [08/18/12,02:42:52] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck
>   indicates Crystal Reports templates for Visual Studio 2010 was not
>   attempted to be installed. [08/18/12,02:42:52] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck
>   indicates Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 (x86) ENU was not
>   attempted to be installed. [08/18/12,02:42:52] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck
>   indicates Visual Studio 2010 Tools for SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 ENU
>   was not attempted to be installed. [08/18/12,02:42:52] VS70pgui: [2]
>   DepCheck indicates Microsoft Sync Framework Runtime v1.0 (x86) ENU was
>   not attempted to be installed. [08/18/12,02:42:52] VS70pgui: [2]
>   DepCheck indicates Microsoft Sync Services for ADO.NET v2.0 (x86) ENU
>   was not attempted to be installed. [08/18/12,02:42:52] VS70pgui: [2]
>   DepCheck indicates Microsoft Sync Framework Services v1.0 (x86) ENU
>   was not attempted to be installed. [08/18/12,02:42:52] VS70pgui: [2]
>   DepCheck indicates Microsoft Sync Framework SDK v1.0 (x86) ENU was not
>   attempted to be installed. [08/18/12,02:42:52] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck
>   indicates Microsoft SQL Publishing Wizard 1.4 was not attempted to be
>   installed. [08/18/12,02:42:52] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates
>   Microsoft SQL Server System CLR Types was not attempted to be
>   installed. [08/18/12,02:42:52] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates
>   Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Objects was not attempted to
>   be installed. [08/18/12,02:42:52] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates
>   Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Express Service Pack 1 (x86) was not
>   attempted to be installed. [08/18/12,02:42:52] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck
>   indicates Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Data-Tier Application Framework
>   was not attempted to be installed. [08/18/12,02:42:52] VS70pgui: [2]
>   DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Data-Tier Application
>   Project was not attempted to be installed. [08/18/12,02:42:52]
>   VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2
>   Transact-SQL Language Service was not attempted to be installed.
>   [08/18/12,02:42:52] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft
>   SharePoint Developer Tools was not attempted to be installed.
>   [08/18/12,02:42:52] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual
>   Studio 2010 ADO.NET Entity Framework Tools was not attempted to be
>   installed. [08/18/12,02:42:52] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates
>   Microsoft Help Viewer 1.0 x86 was not attempted to be installed.
>   [08/18/12,02:49:24] Microsoft Application Error Reporting: [2]
>   CMsiComponent::Install() expects the setup file for Microsoft
>   Application Error Reporting, but the file failed verification.
>   [08/18/12,02:49:24] setup.exe: [2] ISetupComponent::Pre/Post/Install()
>   failed in ISetupManager::InternalInstallManager() with HRESULT
>   -2147467259. [08/18/12,02:49:24] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Application Error Reporting is not installed.
>   [08/18/12,02:49:24] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates VC 9.0 Runtime
>   (x86) was not attempted to be installed. [08/18/12,02:49:24] VS70pgui:
>   [2] DepCheck indicates VC 10.0 Runtime (x86) was not attempted to be
>   installed. [08/18/12,02:49:24] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates
>   Microsoft .NET Framework 4 was not attempted to be installed.
>   [08/18/12,02:49:24] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Windows
>   Installer 4.5 Update (x86) - Windows XP was not attempted to be
>   installed. [08/18/12,02:49:25] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates
>   Microsoft Visual F# 2.0 Runtime was not attempted to be installed.
>   [08/18/12,02:49:25] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual
>   Studio Macro Tools was not attempted to be installed.
>   [08/18/12,02:49:25] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates TFS Object Model
>   (x86) was not attempted to be installed. [08/18/12,02:49:25] VS70pgui:
>   [2] DepCheck indicates .NET Framework 4 Multi-Targeting Pack was not
>   attempted to be installed. [08/18/12,02:49:25] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck
>   indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU was not
>   attempted to be installed. [08/18/12,02:49:25] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck
>   indicates Microsoft Web Deployment Tool (x86) was not attempted to be
>   installed. [08/18/12,02:49:25] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates
>   Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 2 - Visual Studio 2010 Tools was not attempted
>   to be installed. [08/18/12,02:49:25] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates
>   Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 2 was not attempted to be installed.
>   [08/18/12,02:49:25] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft
>   Silverlight was not attempted to be installed. [08/18/12,02:49:25]
>   VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Silverlight 3 SDK was not
>   attempted to be installed. [08/18/12,02:49:25] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck
>   indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime (x86)
>   was not attempted to be installed. [08/18/12,02:49:25] VS70pgui: [2]
>   DepCheck indicates Microsoft Office Developer Tools (x86) was not
>   attempted to be installed. [08/18/12,02:49:25] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck
>   indicates Dotfuscator Software Services - Community Edition was not
>   attempted to be installed. [08/18/12,02:49:25] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck
>   indicates Crystal Reports templates for Visual Studio 2010 was not
>   attempted to be installed. [08/18/12,02:49:25] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck
>   indicates Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 (x86) ENU was not
>   attempted to be installed. [08/18/12,02:49:25] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck
>   indicates Visual Studio 2010 Tools for SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 ENU
>   was not attempted to be installed. [08/18/12,02:49:25] VS70pgui: [2]
>   DepCheck indicates Microsoft Sync Framework Runtime v1.0 (x86) ENU was
>   not attempted to be installed. [08/18/12,02:49:25] VS70pgui: [2]
>   DepCheck indicates Microsoft Sync Services for ADO.NET v2.0 (x86) ENU
>   was not attempted to be installed. [08/18/12,02:49:25] VS70pgui: [2]
>   DepCheck indicates Microsoft Sync Framework Services v1.0 (x86) ENU
>   was not attempted to be installed. [08/18/12,02:49:25] VS70pgui: [2]
>   DepCheck indicates Microsoft Sync Framework SDK v1.0 (x86) ENU was not
>   attempted to be installed. [08/18/12,02:49:25] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck
>   indicates Microsoft SQL Publishing Wizard 1.4 was not attempted to be
>   installed. [08/18/12,02:49:25] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates
>   Microsoft SQL Server System CLR Types was not attempted to be
>   installed. [08/18/12,02:49:25] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates
>   Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Objects was not attempted to
>   be installed. [08/18/12,02:49:25] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates
>   Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Express Service Pack 1 (x86) was not
>   attempted to be installed. [08/18/12,02:49:25] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck
>   indicates Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Data-Tier Application Framework
>   was not attempted to be installed. [08/18/12,02:49:25] VS70pgui: [2]
>   DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Data-Tier Application
>   Project was not attempted to be installed. [08/18/12,02:49:25]
>   VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2
>   Transact-SQL Language Service was not attempted to be installed.
>   [08/18/12,02:49:25] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft
>   SharePoint Developer Tools was not attempted to be installed.
>   [08/18/12,02:49:25] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual
>   Studio 2010 ADO.NET Entity Framework Tools was not attempted to be
>   installed. [08/18/12,02:49:25] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates
>   Microsoft Help Viewer 1.0 x86 was not attempted to be installed.
>
> **

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, It was because of the corrupt ISO. It solved when i downloaded a new one.